# Laravel route with inertia and slash route

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, inertiajs

I installed and configured the inertia on my laravel app and wanted to create also an admin along with the already established single page functionality on my app and wanted to group it under `/admin`

```
    Route::prefix('/admin')->group(function(){
        Route::get('/login',[AdminController::class, 'login'])->name('admin.login');
    });
```

the above route is expected to be accessible at `"<domain>/admin/login"` but not working at all. Any help, suggestions, ideas is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `::prefix('admin')->` without the slash

Answer (score 1):

**1)** `::prefix('admin')` remove slash.

**2)** run  `php artisan route:cache` and it will work!